# Pl Sql pls-00103-encountered-the-symbol / or create

Tags: plsql, oracle-sqldeveloper, pls-00103

i'm trying to use this package https://technology.amis.nl/wp-content/uploads/2021/03/as_xlsx20.txt
to create xls file from a query.

If i paste the code in a package in sql developer, i get the error:
Pl Sql pls-00103-encountered-the-symbol / at line 490, before the CREATE OR REPLACE package body AS_XLSX

Where is the real problem here?

Thank you in advance

Comment: Run the worksheet as a script using `F5` (and not using `CTRL+Enter` as individual statements). Cannot replicate the issue in [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=01ccf27ae625e0dc96a48020269209d7).

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I tried but still the same issue.
I don't know very well pl sql, i just copied the whole source in a package. Maybe some settings are wrong?

Comment: Save that link to a text file or your local machine. Open it in SQL Developer. Run it as a script using `F5` and it should just work. There are no settings that need to be configured.